# Python MySQLdb returning variable amount of rows on same call

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm working on a project but I'm kinda stuck due to a weird problem. I pull data from an external API and save it into my own SQL database with a Python script. After pulling the data I check if it's already present in my database. I do this with the following code snippet:

```
def getDatabaseMatchesForSummoner(summonerId):
    sqlSelect = 'SELECT gameId FROM playerMatchHistory WHERE playerId=%s'
    try:
        cur.execute(sqlSelect,(summonerId,))
        db.commit()
    except MySQLdb as e:
        db.rollback()
        print e
    gameIds = []
    print cur.rowcount
    for i in range(cur.rowcount):
        gameIds += [str(cur.fetchone()[0])]
    return gameIds
```

Now the problem is the following: this piece of code tends to return an amount of rows that are not in agreement with my actual database. For instance, for a particular summoner ID, it returns 7 rows whereas if I enter the query into phpMyAdmin I get 10, the correct amount. I've been searching for some hours now and I can't honestly find anything wrong with it. I tried some other things like fetchall(), other string formatting, etc. I really hope someone can point out what's wrong.

Comment: If you select `gameId, playerId` with no `WHERE` clause, do you get all 10 results, (e.g. `print [row[0] for row in cur.fetchall() where row[1] == '7']` or whatever makes sense)?

Comment: @WayneWerner I seem to get 7 too in that case... I do see though if I iterate that over and over again, suddenly there ARE 10 results

Comment: Copy the 10 `gameId`s from what you get in phpMyAdmin, and see if you're actually missing any from the results. I'm *guessing* that the problem is some kind of spacing/padding/trimming between what phpMyAdmin is doing and what Python is doing and what you have in your database. Meaning, `'7'` is a different ID from `'7 '`. And `'abc123'` *might* be a different ID than `'ABC123'`.

Comment: @WayneWerner So if I enter the following query in phpMyAdmin `SELECT gameId,playerId FROM playerMatchHistory WHERE playerId='33512794'` I get the following 10 gameIds: 2714520459, 2716200199, 2716250961, 2716256621, 2716339829, 2716344757, 2716438694, 2720673891, 2720680220, 2720760622

When I ask for all the gameId, playerId pairs in my Python script and filter out the ones with playerId 33512794 I only get the following 7 the first time the code is executed: 2714520459, 2716200199, 2720673891, 2716250961, 2716256621, 2720680220, 2720760622

Comment: @WayneWerner However, executing it multiple times, after a while I do get the 10 correct results.. I don't get it because my database doesn't change meanwhile

Comment: You don't have multiple different database backends, do you? I'd also probably start checking syslog, dmesg... You may also look into [strace and tcpdump](http://jvns.ca/blog/2016/05/06/a-workshop-on-strace-and-tcpdump/). That's exceedingly bizarre that it takes a few tries to get the full result set, unless you've got some caching going on somewhere.

Comment: @WayneWerner I'm really getting desperate... It's just one MySQL database though, isn't it supposed to just work properly? I honestly don't know what could cause this

Comment: that's what I would expect, but I use Postgres so I don't know what kind of oddness MySQL is capable of. I would try ruling out each part that could go wrong. The easiest thing is data mismatch. Given the behavior where running the same code multiple times produces different results (it was the same code, right?) that seems unlikely. You don't have load balanced dbs so you're not dealing with a propagation issue. Now you're left with two options - something is getting horked up between Python and MySQL or something is getting horked up on the return trip.